# Margin behavior with center align in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` to align my child view center vertically.
But when I add bottom margin to my child view, I find it's only take half of the margin.

**For example**:
[image]

The red view and blue view are center align vertically with 100dp height. Then I add bottom margin (100dp) to the red view. I thought the red view would be on top of the blue view, but it only raise 50dp.

Comment: Thats the expected behavior . If you want Red view on the top of blue one that means its should be constrains against blue view not parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is expected. Let me explain you how:

When you add "marginBottom", you are doing that in reference to what your constraint specifies in constraintBottom (in this case to parent).

Imagine the screen as a paper with x, y axis, imagine it is a square of size 1000.
Without the margin, because of your constraints, your view would have its center in (500, 500) right? The left top corner would be at (450, 550) and right bottom would be at (550, 450).

Now, what happens when you add the margin?

You are basically **reducing the scope of the paper from your view's perspective**. Given your view needs to be 100 away of the parent because of the margin, it is like for your view, the new screen reference is not a square of size 1000, but a rectangle with width = 1000 and height = 900.

Now is when the constraints comes and say, alright center this in this plane and doing some math, you can see that the new center is (500, 450) with the top left corner in (450, 400) and the right bottom corner in (550, 500).

In other words, your margin was split half at the top and half of the bottom because of your new view using this new screen reference once margin was applied.

**What are your alternatives then?**

The best approach would be to use chains, you can chain both views together so that they both are centered and then specify a space between them.

Long story short, rather than constraint your first view to bottom="parent", change it to constraint to your second view. The same for your second view, instead of constraint to top="parent", change it to constraint to your first view and that's it.

Look at this reference to learn more about chains: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout#constrain-chain and find out all the ways you can customize them and how they work :)

Answer (score 2):

That happens because when the view is created, the margin is added first. Then, the position is setted **relative to the remaining space**; so, if your vertical position is the 0.5 (center) your bottom margin will take only this percentage.